# Singleton instanced two times

Tags: c++, cocoa, singleton

I am rewriting this question, cause i realized that i didn't understand the problem when first asking this and the question got really messy.

I have a Singleton-Pattern class (Meyers Singleton) in a Library. When i call getInstance() in my Main-Application and inside a .cpp in that Library i get two different addresses. When i call the getInstance() inside the Librarys header its the same address though.

## main.cpp

```
 #include <GameEngine.h>
 #include <iostream>

 main() {

     GameEngine& engine = GameEngine::getInstance();
     std::cout << &engine;    // gives me address A

     engine.doSomething();

}
```

Now it works fine when calling getInstance in the Headerfile:

## Inside Library GameEngine.h

```
class GameEngine {

public:
    static jglEngine& getInstance() // Singleton is accessed via getInstance()
    {
        static jglEngine instance; // lazy singleton, instantiated on first use
        return instance;
    }
    
    void doSomething() {
        GameEngine& engine = GameEngine::getInstance();
        std::cout << &engine;    // gives me also address A

    }
private:
   GameEngine() {};

   GameEngine(GameEngine const&); // prevent copies
   void operator=(GameEngine const&); // prevent assignments
}
```

But when i don't put the function definition inside the header, but inside the source-file, it gives me a different address:

## Inside Library GameEngine.cpp

```
 #include "GameEngine.h"
 
 void GameEngine::doSomething() {
      
      GameEngine& engine = GameEngine::getInstance();
      std::cout << &engine;    // gives me address B

 }
```

## Found a Solution :D

I changed the dynamic Library into a static Library, which made it work.

Comment: At one time, problems could arise (when using most compilers) if a static member was initialised from different threads.  I'm not sure if this is still the case.

Comment: but i don't use different threads in here, or do i?

Comment: I don't know, since I'm not familiar with Cocoa.  Something worth testing for though.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/7IM9oQ). Please post a complete (but minimal) test case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: sorry, tested it myself an realized i made a mistake when posting it here. Now it should be correct.

Comment: mmh, when i do it in just one File, like you did, it also works for me. So its probably a problem with having the engine in a cocoa framework?

Comment: rewrote the question now, to actually adress the problem, sorry!

Comment: Side remark:  Although your approach with a class method `getInstance()` being both **declared** as well as **defined** in a header file is fine, in general I would advise against it.  Separate your interfaces from their implementation.  Put only declarations in header files.  All definitions (implementation) should be in source files.  Of course, there are some exceptions e.g. templates.

Answer (score 0):

Every DLL gets its own instance of static data, this is actually one of the real problems (but possibly also one of the advantages depending on your perspective) of using a DLL

There are tricks to overcoming this such as using Thread Locale Storage, but often you have to ensure DLLs gets handed passed the singleton, perhaps making the singleton in the main application and then passing that around as some sort of context object.